# How to get XMLHttpRequest responseText returned inside a express.router API function Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make my API function return the XML response. I know XMLHttpRequest is async. I can log the response, but I can't bring the response one level up in the scope. How can I acheive this so I can make my express router function return the response?

I can log the response like this:

```
router.post('/frete', async(req,res) =>{

    try{

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", someUrl);
        xhr.send();

        //return res.send('The elusive XML response')

    }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Server error.')
    }

});
```

I have tried many many tweaks to bring this responseText one level up in the scope, so my API function returns something, but no success.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: here is `this.responseText` is xml response? I mean the response is coming in xml not json right?

Comment: Yes, console.log(this.responseText) prints something like this:  <Servicos><cServico><Codigo>04510</Codigo><Valor>27,80</Valor><PrazoEntrega>9</PrazoEntrega><ValorSemAdicionais>27,80</ValorSemAdicionais><ValorMaoPropria>0,00</ValorMaoPropria><ValorAvisoRecebimento>0,00</ValorAvisoRecebimento><ValorValorDeclarado>0,00</ValorValorDeclarado><EntregaDomiciliar>S</EntregaDomiciliar><EntregaSabado>N</EntregaSabado><obsFim></obsFim><Erro>0</Erro><MsgErro></MsgErro></cServico></Servicos>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. I've added `application/xml` in header which means it'll show xml in response and I've moved res.send inside if condition. because you're sending response at the end of try block but till that time your someurl is not resolved.

```
router.post('/frete', async(req, res) =>{

    try{

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText)
                res.type('application/xml');
                res.send(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", someUrl);
        xhr.send();

    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Server error.')
    }

});
```

Comment: Well, this was very simple. I guess i need some sleep. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that instead of *post* it should not be *get*?

with post send to the server, and you're asking for a send... to recover (?)(sorry I find it strange)

Retrieving the response is possible by making the parse in json and resending it as an object.

```
return JSON.stringify(this.responseText, undefined, 2);
```

---

an idea...

```
router.post('/frete', async(req, res) =>{

    try{

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log("OK");
                retResp(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", someUrl);
        xhr.send();

    } catch(err) {
       ....
    }


    function retResp(resp){
       console.log(resp);
       res.send(resp);
    }    

});
```

Comment: Yes, i need it to be a post, I ommited the request body to simplify things. But I need information sent to the API.